# Java Split Number into Digit's Algorithm

Tags: java

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SplitNumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int num, temp, factor = 1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        num = sc.nextInt();
        temp = num;
        while (temp != 0) {
            temp = temp / 10;
            factor = factor * 10;
        }
        System.out.print("Each digits of given number are: ");
        while (factor > 1) {
            factor = factor / 10;
            System.out.print((num / factor) + " ");
            num = num % factor;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand this int factor's job. Can someone help me to understand this codes algorithm?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger? That should give you an idea.

Comment: `Integer.toString(12345).replaceAll("(\\d)", "$1 ").trim()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In programming languages, if you hold double value in the int,it rounds the number to lower one thus if you do 15/10 it will return 1 as int and if you do 5/10 it will return 0. With this knowledge you can understand.

For example,let the number be 953,

```
while (temp != 0) {
    temp = temp / 10;
    factor = factor * 10;
}
```

> **1.Iteration**  temp = 95 , factor = 10
>
> **2.Iteration**  temp = 9 , factor = 100
>
> **3.Iteration**  temp = 0 , factor = 1000

end of while loop because temp is 0.

```
while (factor > 1) {
    factor = factor / 10;
    System.out.print((num / factor) + " ");
    num = num % factor;
}
```

> **1.Iteration**  num = 953 factor = 100 , 953/100 = 9 (you get first digit)
>
> **2.Iteration**  num = 953%100 = 53 , factor = 10 , 53/10 = 5 (you get second digit)
>
> **3.Iteration**  num = 53%10 = 3 , factor = 1 , 3/1 = 3 (you get last digit)

End of while loop.

Actually it is basic math. When you want to extract nth digit of number, you just have to divide it by 10^n.

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator to extract the rightmost digit or digits from a number. For example, x % 10 yields the rightmost digit of x (in base 10). Similarly x % 100 yields the last two digits.

[Here more info](http://greenteapress.com/thinkapjava/html/thinkjava006.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you would not care about flipping the order of digits, you could simply write

```
int num = sc.nextInt();
do {
  System.out.println(num % 10);
  num = num / 10;
} while(num != 0);
```

The [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `num % 10` calculates the remainder of dividing `num` by `10`, effectively gets the digit at the lowest position ("ones"). `0 % 10` is `0` ... `9 % 10` is `9`, `10 % 10` is `0` again, and so on. Then the division by `10` makes the old "tens" the new "ones", and the entire thing is repeated until `0` remains.

The hassle in your code is about emitting the digits in the "correct" order, highest position first, ones last. So it first checks how many digits are in your number, `factor` grows to the same size in the process. `temp=temp/10;` has the same role as `num=num/10;` in the short snippet (cutting a digit from the number in each iteration), and `factor=factor*10` "adds" a digit to `factor` at the same time. [I just stop here as there is an accepted answer already explaining this]

Comment: Thank you for directly explaining the factor part. =)